# Data Annotations Extensions MV3 ModelState not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am using DataAnnotationsExtensions from http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

with an example from here http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx

Controller Code

```
    public ActionResult Create(Dog dog, HttpPostedFileBase Picture)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^.*\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png)$");
        Match m = rgx.Match(Picture.FileName);

        if (rgx.IsMatch(Picture.FileName))
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
```

Model Code

```
[FileExtensions("png|jpg|jpeg|gif", ErrorMessage = "Only jpg jpeg gif or png files allowed")]
        public string Picture { get; set; }
```

and the razor code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Picture, new { type = "file" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture)
```

Everything I do it fails everytime at

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

If I remove the FileExtensions Annotation it works fine but then I no longer have the ability to block file types that I dont want.

I have gone as far as to check the code for the data annotations extentions located here
https://github.com/srkirkland/DataAnnotationsExtensions/blob/master/DataAnnotationsExtensions/FileExtensionsAttribute.cs

and I still cant seem to find out where the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that some `required` item is not being posted. Since the only item in your model is a `string` it shouldn't be that because strings are nullable. Is that the only thing in your model? If not if there is a `int` (not the id though) or `DataTime`, etc. just add a `?` after it to allow it to be nullable. For example, `public int? SomeNumber { get; set;}`

Comment: All of the items in the model are Strings except for the for the ID. So I still don't know why this does not work when I have the data annotation

Comment: Set a break point, debug and look at the InteliTrace step by step, you may also watch the `Model.State var` and see what's up. Also you can comment out the `if(ModelState.IsValid)` and see if it throws a error.

Comment: if you added this line to your controller code:  dog.Picture = Picture.FileName;, does you code pass model validation?

Comment: @Tommy I tried that and it still shows ModelState as being invalid.

Comment: @scripter78 - another thing to try..rename your HttpPostedFileBase parameter to something else...like uploadedPicture.  I am curious is the model binder is doing 'funky things' when binding.

Comment: @Tommy that did it. I changed the HttpPostedFileBase parameter to Pic instead of Picture and that worked. Thank you.

Comment: @scripter78 - Awesome, I will post as an answer (I was unsure about if that was the root cause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the model binder is getting confused with a property named 'Picture' on your model and a `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter named 'Picture' as well.

If you update your `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter to something other than 'Picture', the model binder should behave normally.  Example:

```
public ActionResult Create(Dog dog, HttpPostedFileBase UploadedPicture)
```